# Issue deleting cells from UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am using UICollectionViewController and I am trying to use deleteItems in a loop of selected items like so:

```
for item in (collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems)!
        {

            let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell

            deleteLandGradingImage(images: ImagesData(jobNo: self.jobNo, ImageBytes: (self.array[item.item]["imageBytes"] as! String), Username: appDelegate.username)) { result in

                cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.editButton]
                self.editButton.isEnabled = true
                self.editButton.title = "Edit"
                self.doneButton.title = "Done"

                self.array.remove(at: item.item)
                self.collectionView?.deselectItem(at: item, animated: true)
                self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [item])

            }

        }


deleteLandGradingImage(images: ImagesData(jobNo: self.jobNo, ImageBytes: (self.array[item.item]["imageBytes"] as! String), Username: appDelegate.username)) { result in
}
```

Is a call to an API that deletes the image inside the cell and removes it from the database.

```
func deleteLandGradingImage(images: ImagesData, completionHandler:@escaping (_ result:Bool) -> Void) {

        //Define array for returning data

        var returnedResults = Bool()

        //Call API

        WebService().deleteLandGradingImages(images: images)
        {
            (result: Bool) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                //Return our results

                returnedResults = result
                completionHandler(returnedResults)

            }

        }

    }
```

and here is the method in WebService:

```
func deleteLandGradingImages(images: ImagesData, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)
    {

        var jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

        //Set Lot

        jsonDict["jobNo"] = images.jobNo

        //Set Image

        jsonDict["imageBytes"] = images.ImageBytes

        let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: .prettyPrinted)

        let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice + "DeleteGradingImages");

        //Assign Username

        urlComponents?.user = appDelegate.username;

        //Assign Password

        urlComponents?.password = appDelegate.password;

        //Define our URL String

        let url = urlComponents?.url;

        //Define URL Request

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        //Set Header Values for request

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        //Set Header Values for request

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        //Set Request Method to POST

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //Set Request Body to JSON Data

        request.httpBody = jsonData

        Alamofire.request(request)
            .responseJSON { response in

                if(response.error != nil)
                {
                    completion(false)
                }
                else
                {
                    let responseString = (String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8) != nil) as Bool
                    completion(responseString)
                }

        }
    }
```

My problem with the loop is that sometimes it works, sometimes I get this error:

> Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of
>   items contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
>   equal to the number of items contained in that section before the
>   update (1), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Sometimes I get this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

on this line

```
self.array.remove(at: item.item)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I got this from an answer:

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let group = DispatchGroup()

        let indexPaths = (collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems)!

        var deletes = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()

        for item in indexPaths {
            deletes.append(self.array[item.item])
        }

        for item in deletes {

            group.enter()

            deleteLandGradingImage(images: ImagesData(jobNo: self.jobNo, ImageBytes: (item["imageBytes"] as! String), Username: appDelegate.username)) { result in

                let i = self.array.index { (dic) -> Bool in

                    return true

                }
                if i != nil {
                    self.array.remove(at: i!)
                    group.leave()

                }

            }

        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            for item in indexPaths {
                let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell
                cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
                self.collectionView?.deselectItem(at: item, animated: true)
            }
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.editButton]
            self.editButton.isEnabled = true
            self.editButton.title = "Edit"
            self.doneButton.title = "Done"
            self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: indexPaths)

            if(self.array.count == 0)
            {
                self.imageCollectionDelegate?.ImageCollectionChange(false)
            }

        }

    }
```

But sometimes I get an error on this line:

```
let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell
```

This is the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

I noticed this only happens on iPhone and if I select images and scroll through the UICollectionView, then click the delete button.

**UPDATE**

I have also tried this:

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        self.createIndicator()

        for item in (collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems)! {

            if let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell? {
                deleteLandGradingImage(images: ImagesData(jobNo: self.jobNo, ImageBytes: (self.array[item.item]["imageBytes"] as! String), Username: appDelegate.username)) { result in

                    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0

                    self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                        self.array.remove(at: item.item)
                        self.collectionView?.deselectItem(at: item, animated: true)
                        self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [item])
                    }) { completed in
                        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.editButton]
                        self.editButton.isEnabled = true
                        self.editButton.title = "Edit"
                        self.doneButton.title = "Done"
                        self.stopIndicator()

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

But I get this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

On this line:

```
self.array.remove(at: item.item)
```

Comment: Comment on your update  : `self.array.remove(at: item.item)` is crashing for you , So could you please print your array before you perform remove operation, and also print item.item below it, You are getting error because item's you are trying to delete  is not exits in your array (array has less element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Updating collectionView in loop which uses `collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems`
2. Calling `collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [item])` too often

Best choice is to perform network requests for all indexes and then remove them from collectionView in one step. You can combine requests in one chain with `DispatchGroup`.

Some explanation: Removing two items. 1 and 2. Sometimes 1 will be removed first, and after that `indexPathsForSelectedItems` will contains just one index(1). But loop will try to remove item at indexPath 2. It's a crash.

Sample of using DispatchGroup with your code:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let indexPaths = (collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems)!
var deletes = [<your type>]()
for item in indexPaths {
    deletes.append(array[item.item])
}
// TODO: Block UI with UIActivityIndicatorView
for item in deletes {
    group.enter()
    deleteLandGradingImage(images: ImagesData(jobNo: self.jobNo, ImageBytes: (item["imageBytes"] as! String), Username: appDelegate.username)) { result in
        let i = self.array.index(of: item)!
        self.array.remove(at: i)
        group.leave()
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.editButton]
    self.editButton.isEnabled = true
    self.editButton.title = "Edit"
    self.doneButton.title = "Done"
    self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: indexPaths)
}
```

Comment: Can I get an example of DispatchGroup using my code?

Comment: I get an error here: let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: What if delete `for item in indexPaths {
        let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell
        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.collectionView?.deselectItem(at: item, animated: true)
    }` ?

Comment: Ill try that now

Answer (score 0):

If you getting the error of

> invalid number of items in section

its because, with any collection change, it expect to have the same number of items than it's source array, you can solve this by using `performBatchUpdates`:

```
for item in (collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems)! {

    if let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as? ImageCollectionCell {
        deleteLandGradingImage(images: ImagesData(jobNo: self.jobNo, ImageBytes: (self.array[item.item]["imageBytes"] as! String), Username: appDelegate.username)) { result in

            cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0

            collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                self.array.remove(at: item.item)
                self.collectionView?.deselectItem(at: item, animated: true)
                self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [item])
            }) { completed in
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.editButton]
                self.editButton.isEnabled = true
                self.editButton.title = "Edit"
                self.doneButton.title = "Done"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I want to put this code? Replace everything in my delete button?

Comment: I get this error with your code: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'ImageCollectionCell' on this line: if let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell {

Comment: I fixed this: Optional type, not 'ImageCollectionCell' by doing this if let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell? {

Comment: However I get a new error when I run the code: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range on this line self.array.remove(at: item.item)

Comment: Still running into the same error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range on self.array.remove(at: item.item)

Answer (score 0):

As all answers above said - you need to use `performBatchUpdates` method for UICollectionView update.

From documentation:

> You can use this method in cases where you want to make multiple
>   changes to the collection view in one single animated operation, as
>   opposed to in several separate animations. You might use this method
>   to insert, delete, reload, or move cells or use it to change the
>   layout parameters associated with one or more cells. Use the block
>   passed in the updates parameter to specify all of the operations you
>   want to perform.

That's simply mean that you need to delete all your items in one time inside `performBatchUpdates` closure.

You can use this code to do that:

```
var indexes: [IndexPath] = []
for item in (collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems)! {
    if let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as? ImageCollectionCell {
        deleteLandGradingImage(images: ImagesData(jobNo: self.jobNo, ImageBytes: (self.array[item.item]["imageBytes"] as! String), Username: appDelegate.username)) { result in
            cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
            self.collectionView?.deselectItem(at: item, animated: true)
            indexes.append(item.item)
        }
    }
}
indexes.forEach { self.array.remove(at: $0) }
collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
    self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexes])
}) { completed in
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.editButton]
    self.editButton.isEnabled = true
    self.editButton.title = "Edit"
    self.doneButton.title = "Done"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should first remove the item from the array than update the database I had a similar issue with my project and this simple change solved the issue. I try to post some code when I get home. Hope this helps.